# why many aws service didn't provide the RESTful API but only the sdk?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services

I studied `Amazon web service` API reference, I found many services (EC2,Cloudwatch) only support the programming SDK, java/python and so on. Only little services provide RESTful API, such as S3.

I think Restful API is more easier to use than programming SDK. Why Amazon didn't provide the Restful API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that REST APIs are preferable to SDKs but, actually, all of the AWS services do expose an HTTPS interface, they're just not "RESTful."  They call it the "Query API."

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/Using_Query_API.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-query-api.html

Answer (score 3):

Some may say it just comes down to opinion... but imo, there's **no reason to prefer lower RESTful API over SDK, when your language of choice has one.**

The SDK's are hand-crafted by AWS to get the most out of their API's (and who would know how to do so better than them?), and give you abstractions that you can take advantage of.

For anything besides a trivial project toying around with AWS, choosing to work with the lower-level API's means that you will end up re-implementing many things the SDK's give you out of the box, aka reinventing the wheel...

The SDK's are there to get you productive and working, fast.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact, all services of AWS in the SDK communicates with POST/GET.
In the documentation of the AWS services, they provide the url of each action.
The only thing you need to do is read the documentation.

See this S3 documentation which you can see how things works:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html